# Custom control statements in clang-format

Tags: c++, c, clang, clang-format

We use macros to instrument control statements, for example

```
IF (baz == 1) {
    // code
} ELSE {
    // code
}
```

Clang-format doesn't recognize these and gets confused. I noticed there is `ForEachMacros` and I was hoping there is something similar for other control statements.

Comment: Don't do this. Use the language's natural statements.

Comment: I don't have a choice in this matter. It's ITU-T mandated.

Comment: In this case, are you including the header the defines the macros?

Comment: @Attie See here: https://github.com/dennisguse/ITU-T_stl2009/blob/master/basop/control.h

Answer (score 0):

I had a look into this, following on from your comment:

> See here: [github.com/dennisguse/ITU-T_stl2009/blob/master/basop/contro‌​l.h](https://github.com/dennisguse/ITU-T_stl2009/blob/master/basop/control.h)

You'll need to `#include <control.h>` in your project so that the macros will get defined.

After that, it looks like you should be able do `#undef WMOPS`, and things will return to '*normal*'.

---

These macros appear to be used for profiling / analysis of the software's operation - importantly how many times each of `for`, `while`, `do`, `if`, `else`, `switch`, `continue`, `break`, `goto` are used during a certain region of execution.

See `g722/decg722.c:446` and `:494`:

```c
            if(header[0] != G192_SYNC){ /* bad frame, (with zero length or valid G.722 length) */
                /* ... */
            } else {  /* good frame, update index memory mem_code and mode memory mem_mode */
#ifdef WMOPS
                setCounter(spe2Id);
                fwc();
                Reset_WMOPS_counter();
#endif
```

Then `:567`:

```c
#ifdef WMOPS
      setCounter(spe1Id);
      fwc();
      WMOPS_output(0);
      setCounter(spe2Id);
      fwc();
      WMOPS_output(0);
#endif
```

The `currCounter` variable is set inside `setCounter()`... Here the counter is selected and reset on `G192_SYNC`, and then information is calculated, and output after the frame has been received.

---

I made a simple version to demonstrate:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef WMOPS
#define FOR(a) for(a)

#else /* WMOPS */

#define FOR(a) \
    if (incrFor(), 0); else for(a)

int myFor = 0;

static __inline void incrFor(void) {
    myFor++;
}
#endif /* WMOPS */

void t(int x) {
    int i;

    FOR (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("x: %d    i: %d\n", x, i);
    }
}
int main(void) {
    t(1);
    t(2);

#ifdef WMOPS
    printf("myFor: %d\n", myFor);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc wm.c -o wm && ./wm
x: 1    i: 0
x: 1    i: 1
x: 1    i: 2
x: 1    i: 3
x: 1    i: 4
x: 2    i: 0
x: 2    i: 1
x: 2    i: 2
x: 2    i: 3
x: 2    i: 4
```

```
$ gcc wm.c -o wm -DWMOPS && ./wm
x: 1    i: 0
x: 1    i: 1
x: 1    i: 2
x: 1    i: 3
x: 1    i: 4
x: 2    i: 0
x: 2    i: 1
x: 2    i: 2
x: 2    i: 3
x: 2    i: 4
myFor: 2
```